# Matplotlib - TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Tags: python, windows, numpy, matplotlib, isinstance

I'm trying to make some plots using the matplotlib library. However, anytime I try to run plt.plot() I get the error:

```
if (isinstance(marker, np.ndarray) and marker.ndim == 2 and
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

in the markers.py script of the library

This particular instance of the error happens when attempting to execute the test code

```
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

Going into the matplotlib source code and changing the instances of isinstance(VarName, np.ndarray) to isinstance(VarName, type(np.ndarray)) removes the error on that particular line though I'd have to change it on every mention of isinstance for it to go away I believe. This is obviously a suboptimal solution.

As a note, creating a numpy array and printing the result of isinstance(array, np.ndarray) also gives me the error, while printing the result of isinstance(array, type(np.ndarray)) correctly returns true, so I don't believe this is an error in matplotlibs use of np.ndarray or it's proper importing of numpy, but instead a persistent issue with my environment as a whole.

I'm using conda to run the virtual environment on a windows machine with python 3.8.10 (the error also occurs on python 3.7) and as far as I'm aware both numpy and matplotlib are up to date and importing correctly.

I'm sure it's a relatively basic error, though I can't for the life of me figure it out, no one else I can find seems to have come across this problem before. At least not with matplotlib or ndarrays.

Comment: This is not reproducible. Update all the appropriate environments please with `conda update --all`

Comment: Make sure you haven't redefined `np.ndarray` earlier in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, so I did actually redefine np.ndarray in a separate script earlier in the code. I hadn't considered this as I didn't realize the new definition could be persistent across multiple scripts.

Simple error or having an '=' instead of ':' when defining a variable